# Fail to see sharing in one computer of 3

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

I have 3 computers, all Ubuntu 13.04. I have shared folders on all which I would like to be able to access on the other computers. For some strange reason the 3rd computer can only see its own shared files. It fails to see the other computers (under Nautilus). The computer is connected to the LAN because it has no trouble printing on a shared network printer.

The other 2 computers see one another and can access all of the shared folders (excluding those on the 3rd computer).

I tried to put in the location window of Nautilus the location of the folder, so as not to depend upon the browse. For example on the 3rd computer I put

smb://ilan-main/mydb

It gave me the error message: Oops! Something went wrong. Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out.

I also tried to connect to the 3rd computer from this one with

smb://ilan-lenovo-g570/temp

and I received the same error. I'm quite sure this used to work, but I'm not sure when it stopped working. (A computer died and had to be replaced and it is possible that it never worked on the new computer which did the replacement.) In any case, I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the IP address of the 3rd computer instead of the hostname (*ilan-main*), using the hostname might be an issue depending on your network configuration or software packages installed.

Comment: Brilliant idea. Why didn't I think of that? It solves the problem. Now the only question is: what is missing that it doesn't know the hostname? BTW, it doesn't know host names in both directions.

Comment: They dont have the same hostnames do they? Hopping not... :) you can also edit your `/etc/hosts` file and specify ip addresses / hostnames combinations to force your system to recognize a hostname and connect it to that IP address.

Comment: No, the name are different but somewhat similar. I have 2 Lenovo laptops, one called ilan-len-g570 and the other ilan-lenovo-g570, along with my desktop ilan-main. The trouble with specifying ips is that after a power failure the router might change them. But at least I can get some work done!